# async methods and internal looping

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, async-await

I have a console app that interacts with an internal web API. It runs correctly sometimes, yet other times it throws exceptions for no reason that I can find.  My only suspicion is that maybe it's because every method I use is not asynchronous.

Here is where it starts:

My console app runs the asynchronous method Process():

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Process().Wait();
}
```

Process() connects to an internal web appi:

```
private static async Task Process()
    {

    using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            http.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:112345/");
            var response = await http.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/PostStuff", data);
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

}
```

Here is the internal web API:

```
    [HttpPost("api/PostStuff")]
    public async Task<string>  PostStuff([FromBody] Data data)
    {
        foreach (var s in MyStuff.GetStuff()
        {
             // for loop that gets data from another class that is not asynchronous
        }
        return stuff;
    }
```

My concern is, the data gathered from the looping  that uses MyStuff.GetStuff() uses methods that are NOT tasks or asynchronous.

Do I need to make sure that every method used within an async method is also async?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to make sure that every method used within an async method is also async?

No, but there's no point in having your WebAPI method be `async` if it doesn't have any asynchronous work to do:

```
[HttpPost("api/PostStuff")]
public string PostStuff([FromBody] Data data)
{
  foreach (var s in MyStuff.GetStuff()
  {
    // for loop that gets data from another class that is not asynchronous
  }
  return stuff;
}
```

This won't solve your exception problems, though.

> My only suspicion is that maybe it's because every method I use is not asynchronous.

No, that wouldn't cause exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I need to make everything async because MyStuff.GetStuff() calls an external webAPI.  So the console app needs to wait for all this WebAPI stuff to finish before it can spit out data to the user.